# Bat file for hide/unhide

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I made a bat file for hide and unhide file folders. but i want to enable/disable inheritance with it. but after hiding files i cant access bat file.i want to help to modify my bat file.Here is my code.

```
@ECHO off    
cls    
:start    
echo hide. all files in this folder
echo unhide. all files in this folder
set /p choice=Type the what do you want to do?

if '%choice%'=='hide' goto hide
if '%choice%'=='unhide' goto unhide
if not '%choice%'=='hide' if not '%choice%'=='unhide' goto :error

:hide
attrib /d /s +s +h
attrib /d /s -s -h unhide.bat
icacls "%CD%" /T /inheritance:r
goto :qqq

:unhide
attrib /d /s -s -h
icacls "%CD%" /T /inheritance:e
goto :aaa    :qqq    echo "File hide successful"  goto end

:aaa
echo "File unhide successful"
goto end    

:error
echo "please enter correct command"
goto:start        
:end
pause
```

Comment: The formatting of the code shown above is broken.  Please edit your question and replace the entire code section so we can see the actual batch file.

Comment: Can you just rearrange the code so that you disable inheritance first?

Comment: @ArunaTelshan To format code, you can put four spaces in front of each line as described at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: i want to disable inheritance without bat file.

Comment: @RGuggisberg the bat file cant open after disable inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this into CMD.exe.

```
attrib -h file.bat
```

If file.bat is your executable, it is only hidden, so you can unhide it by this.

Just replace file.bat with your batch file you need to unhide.

-Pringles